# Dynamic Dropdown - Year, Make, Model - Link final selection to a specific page

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make a year/make/model lookup for an ecommerce website that uses 3dcart as an engine. Unfortunately, 3dcart does not have a module or simple solution, so I have to create this from scratch.

I found a basic solution for the Year, Make, Model lookup on this site, but the URL that is produced is built from the selections. This will not work for my needs. I need to be able to link the final selection to a specific url of my choosing.

For instance, if you were to choose "Lincoln" on the first drop down, then "Continental" on the second, then "1995" on the last, I would need the button to link to a specific url (www.autoparts.com/23cd3d2d2.html) and not one that was built from the selections. I have to do it this way because I am essentially creating a landing page that will have subcategories depending on the selection and those category pages are given an arbitrary URL that I cannot control. Also, there will only be roughly 30 of these category pages, so the same link will be used more than once. So, essentially, once all choices are made, there would be a button that would take you to the URL that I have designated in advance based on those choices.

Here is the current code, which does not yet do what I need:

```
<script>

var makeObject = {
  "Acura": {
    "ILX": ["2015", "2014", "2013"],
     },

}

window.onload = function() {
  var makeSel = document.getElementById("makeSel"),
    modelSel = document.getElementById("modelSel"),
    yearSel = document.getElementById("yearSel");
  for (var make in makeObject) {
    makeSel.options[makeSel.options.length] = new Option(make, make);
  }
  makeSel.onchange = function() {
    modelSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    yearSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
    for (var model in makeObject[this.value]) {
      modelSel.options[modelSel.options.length] = new Option(model, model);
    }
  }
  makeSel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
  modelSel.onchange = function() {
    yearSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
var years = makeObject[makeSel.value][this.value];
for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  yearSel.options[yearSel.options.length] = new Option(years[i], years[i]);
     }
   }
 }


function buildUrl() {
  var url = "/";
  var make = document.querySelector('#makeSel').value;
  var model = document.querySelector('#modelSel').value;
  var year = document.querySelector('#yearSel').value;
  var qs = encodeURIComponent(make + ' ' + model + ' ' + year);
  return url;
}



</script>

<div class="dynamic-dropdown">
  <center>
    <form name="myform" id="myForm">
      <h3 id="dropdown-h3">Search</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <select name="optone" id="makeSel" size="1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select make</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <select name="opttwo" id="modelSel" size="1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select model</option>
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <select name="optthree" id="yearSel" size="1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select year</option>
          </select>
        </li>

          <a href="javascript:window.location.assign(buildUrl());">GO</a>

      </ul>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>
<hr/>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please concise your question and be more obvious to where the problem.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear but I guess not.

A year, make, model lookup has three conditional dropdowns that populate based off of the selections made. Once all three dropdown choices are selected (Chevy// Traverse// 1993 - for instance) you could then click the button below that would take you to the specific page with those parts on it. I need a way to link to that page once all of the selections are made. I have included the code that I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

3Dcart not providing this kind of feature but we can build such using ajax and jQuery.
First, need to arrange category hierarchy according to filter and then using ajax and jQuery, we can build such kind of filters in 3Dcart.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Add possible tags to your question to get relevant answers.